# How to get link linear velocity expressed in a frame of choice

Tags: gazebo, simulation, gz-sim

I'm trying to understand if with Gazebo is possible to get the linear velocity of the link (of its CoM or any other point) expressed in a frame of choice, e.g. its predecessor link frame. I've found only the possibility to get the velocity (and acceleration) referred to the world frame through [this](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1Link.html#a856908df28b5eae8f6396c7b3166ef07) API.

Answer (score 2):

Based on their documentation, this functionality has not been implemented yet. This function is only available in classic Gazebo. A complete list of functions that has been implemented, and remains to be implemented in Ignition can be found here: [Migration from Gazebo-classic: Link API](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/migrationlinkapi.html)

I recommend you doing this transformation yourself:

$$
\vec{v}_{target\_frame/reference\_frame} = R_{world \rightarrow reference\_frame} \cdot (\vec{v}_{target\_frame/world} - \vec{v}_{reference\_frame/world})
$$
where
$$
R_{world \rightarrow reference\_frame}
$$ 
is obtained from `gz::sim::Link::WorldPose`,
and
$$
\vec{v}_{x/world}
$$
is obtained from `gz::sim::Link::WorldLinearVelocity`